# SQL Server 2012 Bug: SP_HELP running slow on nested view with identity column

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2012, nested, sql-server-2014

On SQL Server 2014, it was fast, but on SQL Server 2012, it was slow.
Is it a bug?

You can simply reproduce it by running the code below

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (aaa [int] IDENTITY(1,1), bbb int)
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vtest
AS
SELECT t.aaa, t.bbb
FROM dbo.test t
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vvtest
AS
SELECT t1.aaa, t1.bbb
FROM dbo.vtest t1
GO

EXEC sp_help 'vvtest' -- super slow
GO

DROP VIEW dbo.vvtest
GO

DROP VIEW dbo.vtest
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.test
GO
```

Comment: I have reproduced this on SQL Server 2012.    Not really sure why it's this way, but all the information is still available in the various system views (`sys.objects`, `sys.views`, `sys.schemas`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ViEWS`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, etc...).  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: An internal service is grabbing my database info periodically, causing high cpu usage. Initially I didn't understand why a simple sp_help could cause high cpu.

Comment: voted to move to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced. 100% use of a core with the following call stack

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapContext+0x7a
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1d2
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSuspendThread+0x54
ntoskrnl.exe!KiDeliverApc+0x201
ntoskrnl.exe!KiApcInterrupt+0xd7
sqllang.dll!TCacheStore<CacheClockAlgorithm>::GetNextUserDataInHashBucket+0x102
sqllang.dll!CCache::FProcessEntry+0xdf
sqllang.dll!CCache::FRemove+0x115
sqllang.dll!CCache::RemoveByObjid+0x1d
sqlmin.dll!GetBaseRelation+0xb1
sqlmin.dll!CopyOutIdentityPartIntoVariant+0x53
sqlmin.dll!NmIdtseedWstr+0x1bc
sqlTsEs.dll!CEsExec::GeneralEval+0x1a9
sqllang.dll!CXStmtAssignBase::XretExecute+0x149
sqllang.dll!CXStmtSelectWithoutQuery::XretExecute+0x136
sqllang.dll!CMsqlExecContext::ExecuteStmts<1,1>+0x400
sqllang.dll!CMsqlExecContext::FExecute+0xa33
sqllang.dll!CSQLSource::Execute+0x866
sqllang.dll!CStmtExecProc::XretLocalExec+0x201
sqllang.dll!CStmtExecProc::XretExecExecute+0x4d5
sqllang.dll!CXStmtExecProc::XretExecute+0x38
sqllang.dll!CMsqlExecContext::ExecuteStmts<1,1>+0x400
sqllang.dll!CMsqlExecContext::FExecute+0xa33
sqllang.dll!CSQLSource::Execute+0x866
sqllang.dll!process_request+0x73c
sqllang.dll!process_commands+0x51c
sqldk.dll!SOS_Task::Param::Execute+0x21e
sqldk.dll!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask+0xa8
sqldk.dll!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks+0x29a
sqldk.dll!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint+0x261
sqldk.dll!SystemThread::RunWorker+0x8f
sqldk.dll!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker+0x372
sqldk.dll!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint+0x236
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

So looks to be the same bug as [the one reported here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764353/ident-seed-freezes-on-some-queries)

Comment: Yes, the same one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the work that sp_help does is that it tries to find any underlying identity seed and identity increment for the view. These are the functions it uses to that end that are causing the problem.

```
SELECT ident_seed('dbo.vvtest')
SELECT ident_incr('dbo.vvtest')
```

Go ahead and try it, and you should see similar results.

I can't inspect the innards of those functions, so why they hang for `dbo.vvtest` and not for `dbo.vtest` is a question for Microsoft.

Comment: Right, I think I have to let Dev change their code or we have to upgrade to 2014